# Return list of nodes that are k steps away from a given node in a graph using f#

Tags: f#

I'm trying to do this exercise:
[image]
I have the first part already:

```
let rec makeRoadMap (data:(string * string list) list) = 
    match data with
    | []-> Map.empty
    | ah::at-> (makeRoadMap at).Add(fst ah, setOfDestinations (snd ah))
```

I'm trying to complete this function:

```
let upToManySteps (map:RoadMap) (n: int) (startCity : Destination)=
```

which returns a set of cities that are n step away from the start city.
My idea is to recursively call the method to iterate through the distance n. But I'm stuck please help me find a method to do it.

Comment: For the first part, if building a recursive function is not a must, you should look at the functions of the List, Set and Map modules, especially `List.map`, `Set.ofList` and `Map.ofList`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to what I said in a comment, for the second part, you should also pay attention to the Set<'T> type and the [Set module](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/collections.set-module-%5Bfsharp%5D) functions.

For the second part of your exercise, taking "Andulo" as starting city for example.

If the number of steps is 1, you simply return the 'value' of the "Andulo" key in the RoadMap (`set [City "Bibala"; City "Cacolo"; City "Dondo"]`).

If the number of steps is 2, you should return the union of the values of "Bibala", "Cacolo" and "Dondo" keys (i.e. the union of `set [City "Andulo"; City "Dondo"; City "Galo"]`, `set [City "Andulo"; City "Dondo"]` and `set [City "Andulo"; City "Bibala"; City "Cacolo"; City "Ekunha"; City "Funda"]` which is: `set [City "Andulo"; City "Bibala"; City "Cacolo"; City "Dondo"; City "Ekunha"; City "Funda"; City "Galo"]`.

So the functions you need to build a recursive function according to the upper examples are: `Set.map` (or Seq.map) and `Set.unionMany`.

Answer (score 1):

Here an example to show how you can directly decompose the tuple using patterns in the lambda function arguments, how you can use discriminators (City, Roads) as functions and how to use pipelining so that the code can be read as the algorithm.

- From data
- Map each (string * string list) tuple of the list to a (City, Set) tuple
- Convert the resulting list into a set
- Convert the resulting set into a RoadMap

(string * string list) list -> RoadMap

```
let MakeRoadMap data =
    data 
    |> List.map (fun (str, lst) -> (City str, lst |> List.map City |> Set.ofList))
    |> Map.ofList
    |> Roads
```

We can also have used the function composition operator and avoid to specify the function argument wich type can be infered.

```
let makeRoadMap =
    List.map (fun (str, lst) -> (City str, lst |> List.map City |> Set.ofList))
    >> Map.ofList
    >> Roads
```

Using the same way for the `upToManySteps` function

```
let rec upToManySteps roadMap steps city =
    match roadMap, steps with
    | _, n when n < 0 -> invalidArg "steps" "Must be positive"
    | _, 0            -> Set.empty |> Set.add city
    | Roads map, 1    -> map |> Map.find city
    | Roads map, n    -> map 
                         |> Map.find city  
                         |> Seq.map (fun x -> upToManySteps roadMap (steps - 1) x)
                         |> Set.unionMany
```